# n is a number, but the result is not

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

Here's a formula:

```
(n - e) + (n + 1 - w) + (n + 3 - f) + (n + 6 - s) + (n + 2 - h)
```

`n` is a number, but the result is not.

What is `n` and what is the result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If n is

> One

Then by the following

> (one - e) + (two - w) + (four - f) + (seven - s) + (three - h)
>  
> We get the unusual statement: *On to our even tree*

Perhaps, Nietzsche was discussing plans with his friend and said, "Now,

> " on to our event [Ree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_R%C3%A9e)."